# AngularJS $http.post version of a working $.ajax call returns 401 UNAUTHORISED

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http-headers

I am trying to rewrite a working $.ajax server call to use AngularJS $http.put. The $http version returns 401 unauthorised.

The ajax call I am rewriting looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
 url: domain + "/api/v1/user/logout/",
 timeout: 10000,
 type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json",
 beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", api_user())},
 success: function(data) {
  if (data.success) {
   notify("Thanks for signing out");
       
  }
 }
});
```

The AngularJS equivalent I have written looks like this:

```js
logoutUser: function() {
   var config = {headers:  {
        'Authorization': api_user()
      }
   };
   return $http.post(apiDomain + '/api/v1/user/logout/', config).then(function(response)    {
       return response;
   });
}
```

When this is run the server returns a 401 unauthorised and the 'then' part of the $http.post is not entered.

**EDIT: More information**

Using firebug it says the request headers are:

```js
POST /api/v1/user/logout/ HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:8000

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

Referer: http://localhost:8100/

Content-Length: 40

Origin: http://localhost:8100

X-Forwarded-For: 12.13.14.15

Connection: keep-alive

Pragma: no-cache

Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The POST source, according to Firebug is:

```js
{"headers":{"Authorization":"ApiKey bill:bfab6e5a1fb6e4e405756dcf14a634e86ba05c7b"}}
```

Does this mean the authorisation is being send as data not as a header?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add error function for handling 401 response.

Check below sample code for adding error callback function

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: I don't think he is asking how to handle a 401 response but why is he getting a 401.

Comment: `When this is run the server returns a 401 unauthorised and the 'then' part of the $http.post is not entered.` I think this is the question

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the API/server end point you are hitting they do not all authorize calls from the front-end. Steam community market (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/Feedback) is an example that I have found that angular front-end calls simply are not authorized. I had to do the http calls from the back-end and serve up to the front.

Comment: The $.ajax call is working when run from another app (one that does not use AngularJS). So I am guessing the problem must be at the client rather than server end?

Comment: I have added some more information about the problem from Firebug

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is the data you want to send. The config is the third one.

```
$http.post(apiDomain + '/api/v1/user/logout/', {}, config)
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn't make any difference. Still got 401.

Comment: @BillNoble Did you check if `api_user()` returns something and the header gets actually sent? FWIW: You can omit the parentheses (and single quotes) and write `Authorization: api_user`. Angular will then call the function itself.

Comment: api_user() is returning what I  expect.

Comment: I have added some more information about the problem from Firebug

Comment: @BillNoble According to the Firebug info the code has not been updated as I suggested. Or maybe it has and you need to clear the cache, restart the server etc.